# How to add NativeExpressAdView with Custom Model List Android?

Tags: java, android, casting, android-recyclerview, admob

I was following a tutorial for NativeExpressAdView inside RecyclerView from this [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ads/tree/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample) which was provided by google. In this tutorial List was taken as Object Model Class. But my Recylerview has my own custom Model class name as: Artical. That's why I am doing some changes in my code. My code is below.

ArticleAdapter.java

```
package com.prof.rssparser.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView;
import com.prof.rssparser.Article;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import static com.prof.rssparser.example.R.drawable.placeholder;


public class ArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List <Article> articles;
private int rowLayout;
private Context mContext;


WebView articleView;
private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
private static final int NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;



public ArticleAdapter(List<Article> list, int rowLayout, Context context)
{
     this.articles = list;
     this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
     this.mContext = context;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public TextView pubDate;
    ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        pubDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pubDate);
        image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}

public class NativeExpressAdViewHolder extends ArticleAdapter.ViewHolder {

    NativeExpressAdViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return articles == null ? 0 : articles.size();

}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position % 8 == 0) ? NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE
            : MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return item;
}
public void clearData(){
    if (articles != null)
        articles.clear();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);

        case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            // fall through
        default:
            View nativeExpressLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(
                    viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,
                    viewGroup, false);
            return new NativeExpressAdViewHolder(nativeExpressLayoutView);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position)  {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:

    Article currentArticle = articles.get(position);
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = currentArticle.getPubDate();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
    final String pubDateString = sdf.format(date);

    viewHolder.title.setText(currentArticle.getTitle());

            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(currentArticle.getImage())
                    .placeholder(placeholder)
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(viewHolder.image);


    viewHolder.pubDate.setText(pubDateString);


    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //show article content inside a dialog
            articleView = new WebView(mContext);

            articleView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

            String title = articles.get(position).getTitle();
            String content = articles.get(position).getContent();

            articleView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            articleView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            articleView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            articleView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<style>img{display: inline; height: auto; max-width: 100%;} " +

                    "</style>\n" + "<style>iframe{ height: auto; width: auto;}" + "</style>\n"  + content, null, "utf-8", null);

            android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle(title);
                alertDialog.setView(articleView);
                alertDialog.setButton(android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();

                ((TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
    });
break;
        case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            // fall through
        default:
            NativeExpressAdViewHolder nativeExpressHolder = (NativeExpressAdViewHolder) viewHolder;
//i know below casting is wrong but what is right method for this?


      NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView)(Object)articles.get(position);
            ViewGroup adCardView = (ViewGroup) nativeExpressHolder.itemView;


            if (adCardView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                adCardView.removeAllViews();
            }
            if (adView.getParent() != null) {
                ((ViewGroup) adView.getParent()).removeView(adView);
            }

            // Add the Native Express ad to the native express ad view.
            adCardView.addView(adView);
        }
    }
}
```

Artical.java

```
package com.prof.rssparser;

import java.util.Date;


public class Article  {

private String title;
private String author;
private String link;
private Date pubDate;
private String description;
private String content;
private String image;

public String getTitle() {

    return title;

}

public String getAuthor() {

    return author;

}

public String getLink() {

    return link;

}

public Date getPubDate() {

    return pubDate;

}

public String getDescription() {

    return description;

}

public String getContent() {

    return content;

}

public String getImage() {

    return image;

}

public void setTitle(String title) {

    this.title = title;

}

public void setAuthor(String author) {

    this.author = author;

}

public void setLink(String link) {

    this.link = link;

}

 public void setPubDate(Date pubDate) {

    this.pubDate = pubDate;

}

public void setDescription(String description) {

    this.description = description;

}

public void setContent(String content) {

    this.content = content;

}

public void setImage(String image) {

    this.image = image;

}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "Article{" +
            "title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", author='" + author + '\'' +
            ", link='" + link + '\'' +
            ", pubDate=" + pubDate +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", content='" + content + '\'' +
            ", image='" + image + '\'' +
            '}';

}

}
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.prof.rssparser.Article cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
                                                                          at com.prof.rssparser.example.ArticleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ArticleAdapter.java:201)
                                                                          at com.prof.rssparser.example.ArticleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ArticleAdapter.java:48)
```

As you can see I Cast `Object` to `Artical` by `(Object)articles.get(position)`. Is it wrong to use Casting or is there any other way to approach this? How can I  add NativeExpressAdView with Custom Model List. Please help me and sorry for bad formatting, I am a noob.

Comment: Roan Fourie thanks for improve editing.

Comment: Did u solved your problem, Am facing the similar issue , Please post the answer if u have solved the problem

Comment: Did you solve this issue?