# Using different views in onCreateViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, admob, android-viewholder

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZCZSeFTvyk) tutorial by Google Developer's YouTube channel to implement AdMob native express ads.

I got the following error:

```
required: packagename.adapter.viewHolder
found   : packagename.adapter.NativeExpressAdViewHolder
```

Here is how my `onCreateViewHolder` look like:

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            View nativeExpressLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_express_add_container, parent, false);
            return new NativeExpressAdViewHolder(nativeExpressLayoutView); 
        case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            default:
            View myLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(myLayoutView);
    }
}
```

and here is my 2 different ViewHolder classes:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {      

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }          
}

public class NativeExpressAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    NativeExpressAdViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}
```

Here is simular questions with no answers:

- [Error "Incompatible types" while adding NativeAds in recyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140421/error-incompatible-types-while-adding-nativeads-in-recyclerview)
- [How to add NativeExpressAdView with Custom Model List Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45913734/how-to-add-nativeexpressadview-with-custom-model-list-android)

---

**EDIT:**

Here is my full adapter as requested:

```
public class MainActivityVideoAdapter extends Adapter<MainActivityVideoAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList;
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
View myLayoutView;
ArrayList<PathModel> ThumbPathList;
ArrayList<PathModel> VideoPathList = new ArrayList();
static DBManager manager;
long _id;

private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
private static final int AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    //Video Title
    TextView videoName;
    //Video Image
    CircularImageView videoThumb;
    //PopupMenu
    ImageButton viewholderOtions;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        viewholderOtions = (ImageButton) myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.viewholderOptions);
        videoName = (TextView) myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
        videoThumb = (CircularImageView) myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.VideoThumbnail);
        //View onClick
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Popup onClick
        viewholderOtions.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    //Handling click events
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == viewholderOtions) {

            int position = (int) v.getTag();

            showPopupMenu(viewholderOtions, position);
        }

    }
}

public class NativeExpressAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    NativeExpressAdViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}

public MainActivityVideoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PathModel> ThumbPathList, ArrayList<PathModel> VideoPathList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.ThumbPathList = ThumbPathList;
    this.VideoPathList = VideoPathList;
}

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            View nativeExpressLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_express_add_container, parent, false);
            return new NativeExpressAdViewHolder(nativeExpressLayoutView);
        case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
        default:
            View myLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(myLayoutView);
    }
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder myHolder, final int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case AD_VIEW_TYPE:

        case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
        default:

            final PathModel videoPathModel = this.VideoPathList.get(position);
            PathModel thumbathModel = this.ThumbPathList.get(position);
            File file = new File(videoPathModel.getPath());
            String filename = file.getName();
            myHolder.videoName.setText(filename);
            myHolder.videoThumb.setImageURI(Uri.parse(thumbathModel.getPath()));
            myHolder.viewholderOtions.setTag(position);

            myHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                
                Intent intent= new Intent(context, VideoPlayerActivity.class);              
                intent.putExtra("fromFA2", "fromFA2");
                context.startActivity(intent);



                }


            });

    }


}
```

Comment: Similar 'questions'?? There's no question here in the first place!

Comment: `@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                      int viewType) { }` use this Viewholder.

Comment: please post complete adapter, that will helpfull to figureout which classes you used.

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya I have added my full Adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @ClassA i found that you have been importing local class rather than `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` in `onBindViewHolder()`

Please go through below code, this may help you.

```
public class MainActivityVideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

/*
------------------
your constructor goes here
-----------------
*/

 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder myHolder, final int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType) {
            case AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            break;

            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            break;
        }
    }

   public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                View nativeExpressLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_express_add_container, parent, false);
                return new NativeExpressAdViewHolder(nativeExpressLayoutView);
            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                View myLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
                return new ViewHolder(myLayoutView);
        }
    }

   class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public class NativeExpressAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        NativeExpressAdViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't contain your variables and logic, This code is for perfect import and use of methods.

If this resolve your problem, please make this answer approved. 
Happy Coding.

Comment: Basically copied what me and the other guy said 1 hour before you. Nice. Real nice.

Answer (score 1):

I have my doubts that calling the class `ViewHolder` messed you up. Call it rather `MenuViewHolder` or something, cause now when writing simply `ViewHolder` in the method like this:

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
```

It assumes that you're thinking of your OWN class `ViewHolder`, rather than the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and then the types are incompatible. You can fix it by either changing the class name to something else *or* by changing the method declaration to:

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
```

> Although the latter would solve it as well, I'd opt for name changing, cause it's not a good practice to have classes with same names as native ones (e.g. `View`, `ViewHolder`, `BaseAdapter` etc.) cause it might produce confusion as it did here.

Comment: changing it to `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` did not work, can you please elaborate more on your second point about changing the name changing?

Comment: Yes. *"and here is my 2 different ViewHolder classes:"*. You need to change the name of the first class to something better, like `MenuViewHolder`. and don't forget to inflate that one in `case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried but I'm not sure I understand you correctly, I have added my full adapter, can you please edit your answer and indicate to me, sorry once again for not understanding...

Comment: @ClassA man I basically wrote the same thing the "accepted" answer did, and yet you have accepted his answer an hour later, and his solution is the one you said didn't work. . .

Comment: Yes I know, but I could only accept one answer, even though you answered first and his is basically the same as your, I felt that his answer helped me more in understanding what was wrong. I did up-vote yours and I'm sorry for not accepting yours, but I can only accept one.

Comment: No hard feelings, but I literally wrote "It assumes that you're thinking of your OWN class ViewHolder" hoping that'd clarify the problem, and then I offered not one, but 2 solutions :D

Comment: Once again sorry for that and thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

use RecyclerView's ViewHolder, not your ViewHolder.

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            View nativeExpressLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_express_add_container, parent, false);
            return new NativeExpressAdViewHolder(nativeExpressLayoutView); 
        case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            default:
            View myLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(myLayoutView);
    }
}
```

Comment: changing it to `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` did not work.